# Why Sass is good?

Tags: css, sass

I still don't understand what are the real advantages of Sass : http://sass-lang.com/ . Can you guys help me ? In which situations is good to use it and how should it be used to leverage the CSS? thanks

Comment: I suggest reading [this article](http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2012/04/12/ten-reasons-you-should-be-using-css-preprocessor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good article I came across from HackerNews that helped educate me on the advantages of these sort of preprocessing langauges. SASS and LESS are compared, but it provides a good look at why you might use them.

http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/

Comment: That is a great article. I have been using LESS for a while now, but have considered switching to Sass.